# Nest JS Circular dependency Can't resolve in context

Tags: nestjs, nest

Hihi

I have a Contract service that look like this

```js
//contract.service.ts
export class ContractExtService {

  constructor(
    private readonly contractAttachmentService: ContractAttachmentExtService,
  ) {}

...
}
```

And I can attach files to it

```js
@Injectable()
export class ContractAttachmentExtService {

  constructor(
    private readonly contractService: ContractExtService,
  ) {}

  get user(): User {
    return this.request.user;
  }

...
}
```

I have a circular dependency because of other features that we have and other functionalities.

My contract.module looks like this

```js
@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Contract]),
    forwardRef(() => ContractAttachmentModule),
  ],
  controllers: [ContractExtController],
  providers: [ContractExtService],
  exports: [TypeOrmModule, ContractExtService],
})
export class ContractModule {}
```

and the attachments like this

```js
@Module({
  imports: [
    forwardRef(() => ContractModule),
  ],
  controllers: [ContractAttachmentExtController],
  providers: [
    ContractAttachmentExtService,
  ],
  exports: [ContractAttachmentExtService],
})
export class ContractAttachmentModule {}
```

But I'm still getting this wild error

```
Nest can't resolve dependencies of the ContractExtService (?). Please make sure that the argument dependency at index [0] is available in the ContractModule context.
```

Does this have a solution?

I already tried with

```js
// @Inject(forwardRef(() => ContractAttachmentExtService))
```

in BOTH constructors but what started happening was that all the rest of the injected dependencies were undefined

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue before, however the official document is making things confused: https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/circular-dependency.

For your case, you need to apply the forward reference to both `services` and `modules` together.

Please refer to the fix in my project: https://github.com/subquery/indexer-coordinator/commit/0df1fbeda48aaddf5d4918027cf476bc04b94ab6